# Prove that if $u$ is a least squares solution of $Bx = b$ then $u$ $=$ $R^{-1}$ ($Q^T$) $b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

Let $B$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, whose columns are linearly independent. Suppose
that $B$ has a $QR$ factorization, i.e., $B = QR$ where $Q$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with
orthonormal columns and $R$ is an $n \times n$ upper triangular matrix with positive entries along its diagonal. Show that if $u$ is a least squares solution of $Bx = b$ then $u$ $=$ $R^{-1}$$Q^T$ $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** *The least squares solution is unique.*
Note that $\mathrm{Nul}\,B^T B = \mathrm{Nul}\,B$. Since the columns of $B$ are linearly independent, $\mathrm{Nul}\,B=\{0\}$ and hence $\mathrm{Nul}\,B^T B = \{0\}$. Since $B^T B$ is square, it is invertible. Hence there is a unique solution to the least squares equation $B^T B x = B^T b$, namely $x= {(B^T B)}^{-1}B^T b$.

**Step 2:** *$u = R^{-1}Q b$ is the least squares solution.*
Fill in $B=QR$ in the expression $x={(B^T B)}^{-1}B^T b$ and you get
$$
 \begin{align*}
x  &= {(R^T Q^T Q R)}^{-1}(Q R)^T b  \\
   &= {(R^T R)}^{-1} R^T Q^T b \\
   &= R^{-1}{(R^T)}^{-1}R^T Q^T b \\
   &= R^{-1}Q^T b.
\end{align*}
$$